# Want to export complete html table data with formatting and grids to single cell of excel using php

Tags: php, excel

This is my first post.

I want to export my html table data to single cell of excel.

If i use table tags, it throws output data to new lines or cells.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here, nobody is there to code a script for you. When you face a problem, first do some research (use google, search this site itself, etc.) Then you'll definitely come to a general idea of what your problem might be. Now apply your research in your work. See if it works or not. If there is no luck, do not hesitate to ask your question here. Programmers from all around the world will be more than happy to guide you further. (You will be able to show them what you have done so far by then) :D

Comment: So what are you trying at the moment? And do you expect all the HTML formatting to be retained in that cell?

Comment: Hi sid, thanks for the post. I am a php programmer since last 2 years. i have never asked helped from anyone till now. this is the problem may be never anyone has faced , so i have to make a request to everyone across the world who has done this kind of thing.  after doing all research form my side i came to this forum. . By the way i know 4 different ways to generate excel via php but all of them spreads data in different cells.
so... :D. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after struggling for 3 days, found answer by my self.

I used gd library functions to create big image like table and put smaller boxes (with borders) in it which gave effect of table cells.

I used PHP-Excel 2007 to flush the image in different different cells like A1,B1,C1 .

So, thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the following lines on your page top:

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=myfile.xls");
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Comment: thanks.
But not useful. Spreads data in different cells and tables..!

Comment: See i want simlple html table data with 4-5 rows and 5 columns to the A1 cell of excel sheet only. I can put unformatted data into the a1 cell , but the client requires the table grids also. :( and its not possible to do it without table tag ...